# Getting a 200 from the Google Books API, but unable to get items back ie, 'books'. What should I do differently?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, command-line-interface

i'm working on a Command Line Interface, (CLI) in Node and Javascript and I am tasked with returning 5 books from the Google API.

Getting a 200 response when I call the API, but no items(books). What am I missing?

this is my command file

search.js

```
export async function search (keyword) {

  try {

    const results = await axios.get(
      `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${keyword}&printType=books&startIndex=0&maxResults=5&projection=lite`
    );

    console.log(results);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.message === 'Request failed with status code 503') {
      throw new Error(
        "Sorry, there's been a problem. It's likely that you have used a keyword that could not be found on the Google Books API. database. Please try again."
      );
    }
    console.error(error);
    return error;
  }
};
```

confige.js file (here is my configure file)

```
import {validateApiKey} from './utils';

//Config file is for validating users’ configuration inputs when making HTTP request & setting API Key.  

//Goal is to search by keyword to return 5 books with the book's author, title, and publishing company., get book ID to save as reading list.

export const configKey = '8th-google-cli';

export async function configure(args) {

  const config = new Conf();
  let currentConfigObject = config.get(configKey);
  currentConfigObject = currentConfigObject || {};

  let apiKey = args.apiKey || args.apikey || args['api-key'] || args.key || args.k;
    if(!apiKey){
        apiKey = currentConfigObject.apiKey;
    }

    if(!validateApiKey(apiKey)){
        return;
    }
}
```

utils.js (this is not saving the API key)

```
   
import axios from 'axios';
import chalk from 'chalk';

export function validateApiKey(apiKey) {
  if (!apiKey || apiKey.length !== 32) {
    console.error(
      chalk.redBright(
        `API Key for Google Books has not been set up yet.`
      )
    );
    console.warn( // book config -k={your api key}
      `Please use command ${chalk.greenBright(
        'book config --apiKey'
      )} to save your API key.
        `
    );
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

export async function queryBook( apiKey) {
    const baseUri = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${keyword}&printType=books&startIndex=0&maxResults=5&projection=lite';
    const url = getApiUrl(baseUri,apiKey);
    return await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: url
    });
  }
```

Comment: what is exactly the issue with the code you have now?

Comment: im getting back the below, but no books. just a bunch of other stuff such as statusTex etc. 
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: ontent-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',